# single value is only returned on Passing the Dictionary data to Controller string method using jquery post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

single value is only returned on Passing the Dictionary data to Controller string method using jquery post

```
//Jquery
     $("#btnrecieve").click(function () {//fire  on button click

                var data = {};

                //gets each selected checkbox
                $(".chbbox:checked").each(function (index, item) {

                    data['myDictionary[' + index + '].Key']="Remarks";
                    data['myDictionary[' + index + '].Value'] = $(this).val();
                });
                console.log(data);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/UserAcceptSave',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (result) {

                    }
                });

            });
```

My controller to fetch posted Dictionary

```
   public string UserAcceptSave(Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary)
                {
          return Content("hello world");

        }
```

Comment: Please explain, could not understand the problem is.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BabyDuck , I am sending multiple parameters which is selected by checkbox in list. I am able to fetch all the values from jquery console however only the lasst value is being posted to the controller  via the ajax post method

Comment: i am working with dictionary becoz i need both the parameter name and value

Comment: Because you return multiple dictionary entries with the same Key. What are you actually trying to do? You may as well just return an array of strings and make the method parameter `string[] values`

Comment: data['myDictionary[' + index + '].Key']="Remarks";  As you can see i am using index which is increment every time in each function.How  can u get parameter name and value  using array.i need both of them on the same index which is not possible using array.

Comment: @manishkharwal, The key in a dictionary must be unique - you are generating a dictionary where the keys for each item in the collection is `Remarks`. But what is the point of this. Why do you think you need a dictionary? You can just create an array of the values in the checkboxes and post back to `string[] values`

Comment: $("#btnrecieve").click(function () {  
                var data = {};
                //gets each selected checkbox
                $(".chbbox:checked").each(function (index, item) {
                    data['myDictionary[' + index + '].Key']="Remarks";
                    data['myDictionary[' + index + '].Value'] = $(this).val(); $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/UserAcceptSave',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (result) {               }
                });
                });
                  });